# TemplateDoesNotExist after running app on Heroku, locally works fine

Tags: django, heroku

My app works fine locally with production settings and database, and I deployed the app to Heroku successfully.
Here is my project structure:

```
root folder
 env
 src
  app
  fund
  static
  staticfiles
  templates
   includes
    funds_table.html
    pagination.html
   about_me.html
   base.html
   index.html
  user_account
  manage.py
 requirements.txt
 Procfile
 .gitignore
```

Here is my settings for templates:

```
   TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I checked that `os.path.join(BASE_DIR)` returns the right path - `project_root/src`.
When I open the app on Heroku, I receive the error:

```
 raise TemplateDoesNotExist(", ".join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
 django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html, fund/fund_list.html
 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

What is interesting, I don't even have the `fund/fund_list.html` in my app. I tried to use `Search Everywhere` in Pycharm, and this file doesn't exist and even hasn't been mentioned anywhere. I'm not sure why Heroku tries to find it.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
[os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'templates'] #You did wrong here. it should not like this
```

Add this:

```
[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Try above and upload again and see if it solves the problem.